# Get list of gems being used by a Bundler project

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is there a way to get the list of gems or paths to gems that are being loaded for the current project by Bundler (it's a Rails 3) project.

I'm looking for something like:

```
Gem.path
```

but that returns only the ones being actively required by Bundler in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I was looking for was this:

```
Gem.loaded_specs.values.map { |g| g.full_gem_path }
```

Comment: This works when you're only interested in gems that are currently required. If you want all the gems in your bundle, you can use `Bundler.load.specs` instead of `Gem.loaded_specs.values`.

Comment: To add to @method answer, you can also do `Bundler.load.specs.sort.map(&:full_name)`, which will return an array of all gems including full_name and version being used in current project.