# time_splitter gem getting uninitialized constant Sheet::TimeSplitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have installed the `time_splitter` gem so that I can use a single `date_time` field.  My bundle includes version 1.0.0.  As recommended [here](https://github.com/shekibobo/time_splitter), I added this code to my class `Sheet`:

```
extend TimeSplitter::Accessors
split_accessor :event_time
```

I am getting an error on the `extend`:

```
NameError in SheetsController#new
uninitialized constant Sheet::TimeSplitter
```

I'm about to give up and hack together a date/time solution but was hoping for something more elegant. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I was able to add the `time_splitter` gem to a Gemfile of a new Rails 4.2.1 project, ran `bundle`, and could use the the additional accessors added by the gem. I restarted the server somewhere along the way. Check to make sure the gem is getting loaded: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195944/2464

Comment: Can I ask you @slothbear how many times will I forget to restart the server?  Thank you for taking the time to test and post this comment.

Comment: @slothbear - were you able to get it to take formats like "mm/dd/yyyy" for date?  I tried adding `, format: "%m/%d/%Y" to the `split_accessor` but it still failed at `Date.parse` within the gem due to bad format.

Comment: Ha. Once you remember to restart the server, you'll learn something new to forget. Failure at Date.parse is different than error on the extend. Please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your server. Happened to me :)